# custom menu action sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I added custom menu action(SPUserCustomAction) to a SharePoint list on Feature activation.

I can set the url like this:

customAction.Url = '/dummypage.aspx/?DummyItemID={ItemId}';

I would like to get the item using {ItemId} as I am trying to set the url by **not** using {ItemId}. 
Is it possible to get the item like this inside feature activation method while creating SPUserCustomAction?

SPlistItem item = web.Lists["MyList"].GetItemById({ItemId});

I am getting error while trying it and ran out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've a got massive headache when reading "I would like to get the item using {ItemId} as I am trying to set the url by not using {ItemId}". It's contradictory no ? I don't really understand your needs.

Comment: Lol sorry for the confusion. I am trying to do like this SPlistItem item = web.Lists["MyList"].GetItemById({ItemId}) in feature activation.